# Questions pertaining to ongoing competitions

Tags: discussion

As part of the International Astronomy and Astrophysics Competition, the [pre final round question sheet](https://iaac.space/docs/problems/2020/IAAC_Pre_Final_Round_2020_ah379db35h01gw.pdf) has been released. Should questions regarding answers to the paper be closed, or at least have an 'answer embargo' of sorts until this section of the competition finishes in a week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we should lock these posts until after the competition is done. If you see posts that needed to be locked for this reason, please flag them with a custom flag and reference which competition question the post is related to.

This applies only to new questions. Existing questions from before the competition began are still fair.